# apache commons httpclient 4.3.5 via http proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am struggling with a problem since about two days now and seem not to find a solution.

In order to improve support for system proxy settings in our product, I wrote a test-application, to do some testing against a small http proxy server, i run in a docker image.

On the one hand side I do a connection with ordinary URL.openStream()... Which works pretty nice. It recognizes my developer box settings, which i point to the docker run squid or tinyproxy and it can download a file from the web.

The i do the same test with an httpclient 3.X and 4.X. Both fail with timeout-erros when connecting to both proxies.
As both have the same behaviour, I just pick my httpclient 4.x configuration to show:

```
public void testDownloadWithHTTPClient4() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DOWNLOADTEST httpclient 4.x");
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000)
            .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000).build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setRoutePlanner(new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault()))
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(DOWNLOADURL);
        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        ResponseHandler<Boolean> resStreamHandler = new ResponseHandler<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String currentDirectory = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
                    File destinationFile = new File(currentDirectory, myfile.war");
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(entity.getContent(), destinationFile);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }
            }
        };

        httpclient.execute(httpget, resStreamHandler);
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

I also call before

```
public void prepareProxysettings() {
    // try to get system preferences for proxy-settings
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
}
```

The result is, that the client seems to recognize, that a proxy is to be used, but then fails with the following exception:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.16.7.48:6666 [/172.16.7.48] failed: Connect timed out
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:132)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:371)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
[...]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:125)
```

Now I am stuck, not knowing, what to do. Obviously the proxy settings are not that wrong, as my ordinary download with URL works. Also the httpclient recognizes the need to have a proxy. But why does it send a request, which is not understood by both different http proxies?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ProxyTunnelDemo.java

Comment: Thanks Robert!
Looking at this class, this leaves me with the impression, that i am missing something here? I found the examples, demonstrating setting up a proxied connection like I did in my code above. What is "wrong" about that? Why would I have to drill down to the underlying socket? I tested this both with squid and tinyproxy and the behaviour is the same with both.
I expected, that setting the proxy on the http-client level like in the "Request via a proxy" example or via the routing, would lead to the client sending http-connections via the proxy.

Comment: no need to be involve at the socket if u are simply setting a proxy. this was just to give practical example of some of the apache classes/packages.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I think I found out, what was going wrong with my setup.
Stupid me, configured my developer desktop (win7) to use my testproxy. But I left the default behaviour in place, which is like use this proxy for all possible types of connections. If I do this, I get the described timouets with the httpclients.

As soon as I configure the proxy for http-connections only all ways of downloading work nicely and tinyproxy's log prove, that my connections are routet through the proxy.